# How to make JsonProperty() attribute have a dynamic propertyName?

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

Essentially I have a Root class to serialize/deserialize JSON data that looks like this:

```
    public class Root
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string JoystickName { get; set; }

        public Root(string joystickName)
        {
            JoystickName = joystickName;
        }
        
        [JsonProperty("g")]
        public string G { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = JoystickName)] // This line produces error
        public DxsJoyConfig Joystick { get; set; }
    }
```

*EDIT:

How do I change the property name at runtime?

I'm also running into an object reference error required at the indicated line. How can I make an instance of JoystickName within the attribute?

Comment: You can't. Attributes aren't methods. They're generated at compile time and stored in the executable. If you want to find out how to change the property name at runtime, ask that

Comment: Not an answer, but having the *instance constructor* for your `Root` class set a **static value** seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Why isn't JoystickName a property?

Comment: You will need a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for this.  But why is `JoystickName` a static?  What happens if you have multiple `Root` objects in memory?  It's hard to answer your question without understanding the scope of `JoystickName`.  If it's really a per-session setting then probably a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) should be used instead.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will make the edit now thanks for the help

Comment: @dbc Thanks for the reference, I made an edit that will hopefully answer a few concerns.

Comment: Contact the Owner of the API, and ask for non dynamic content would be the course I would go. This clearly seems to be a bad behavior of the API. In fact, If I would be the owner, `JoystickName` would be a property of `DxsJoyConfig`. Probably `DxsJoyConfig` would be an array.